# Aggregate table before join MySQL (GROUP BY)

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, where-clause

I need to agregate a table before joining it with other tables.

```
wp_postmeta GROUP BY wp_postmeta.post_id
```

Is it possible? Where should I put it in? Here is my code:

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.ID, wp_terms.slug
FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN wp_terms ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id


WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'my-type'
   AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
   AND wp_terms.slug IN
      ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
   AND
   (
        wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'exclude' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value <> '111'
        OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'include' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '22'
        OR wp_postmeta.meta_key <> 'include' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key <> 'exclude'
   )
```

Found a new way of doing it while testing ruakh example. I don't know why it works, but it does:

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.ID, wp_terms.slug
FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN wp_terms ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'my-type'
   AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
   AND wp_terms.slug IN
      ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
   AND NOT wp_posts.id IN                # ADDED NOT
   (
      SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id
        FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'exclude' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '111'  #SINCE NOT ABOVE I CHANGED <> to =
           OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'include' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value <> '22'  #SINCE NOT ABOVE I CHANGED = to <>
           #I DELETED THIS LINE
   )
```

Now the query gives back data if include or exclude isn't set. And if they are it checks the ID.

Any comments on my change?

MORE IMPROVEMENTS:

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.ID, wp_terms.slug
FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN wp_terms ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id

WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'my-type'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_terms.slug IN
('field1', 'field2', 'field3')

AND wp_posts.id NOT IN
(
SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id
FROM wp_postmeta

WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'exclude'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IN
('$id', '$id,%', '%,$id,%', '%,$id')

OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'include' 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value NOT IN
('$id', '$id,%', '%,$id,%', '%,$id')
```

Example of what the wp_postmeta table might look like:

**Senario 1 - Only pages with id 18 shall get the data:**

```
meta_id     post_id     meta_key    meta_value
1           30          include     18
2           30          _edit_lock  1322225789:1
3           30          _edit_last  1
```

**Senario 2 -Pages with id 18 shall not get the data:**

```
meta_id     post_id     meta_key    meta_value
1           30          exclude     18
2           30          _edit_lock  1322225789:1
3           30          _edit_last  1
```

**Senario 1 - All pages shall get the data:**

```
meta_id     post_id     meta_key    meta_value
2           30          _edit_lock  1322225789:1
3           30          _edit_last  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should be doing a real join to `wp_postmeta` at all, since you don't actually need anything from it; rather, you should perform a "semi-join", using an `IN` or `EXISTS` clause. For example:

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.ID, wp_terms.slug
FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN wp_terms ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'my-type'
   AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
   AND wp_terms.slug IN
      ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
   AND wp_posts.id IN
   (
      SELECT DISTINCT wp_postmeta.post_id
        FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'exclude' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value <> '111'
           OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'include' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '22'
           OR wp_postmeta.meta_key <> 'include' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key <> 'exclude'
   )
```

Comment: ruakh, I have updated my question. Do you have any comments on my new example?

Comment: @Hakan: If `wp_postmeta.post_id` is unique -- that is, if two distinct `wp_postmeta` records will always have distinct values for `post_id` -- then your new example looks perfect to me. My only comment would be that it's more usual to write "___ NOT IN (...)" than "NOT ___ IN (...)"; but there's no real difference there, so your way is 100% fine.

Comment: I am starting to get a hang of this now (I think). I have updated the question again. Tough post_id will be listed on multiple rows in table wp_postmeta. I will add examples in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html